# Blender cmake error

Tags: makefile, cmake, blender

I'm installing the blender 2.69 to use with MORSE but I'm getting this error when typing "make install":

```
Generating ../../../source/creator/buildinfo.h
-- Found Subversion: /usr/bin/svn (found version "1.6.17")
CMake Error at /opt/ros/dependencies/blender/blender-2.63a/build_files/cmake/buildinfo.cmake:29 (file):
  file Internal CMake error when trying to open file:
  /opt/ros/dependencies/blender/blender-2.63a/build/source/creator/buildinfo.h.txt
  for writing.


make[2]: ** [../source/creator/buildinfo.h] Erro 1
make[1]: ** [source/creator/CMakeFiles/buildinfo.dir/all] Erro 2
make: ** [all] Erro 2
```

please someone could help?

Comment: Permission problem? Disk full?

Comment: nothing, i've used sudo, and the disc has more than 70gb.

Comment: Did you do `make` first without sudo, then `sudo make install`?

Comment: Sudo that was my problem, I've sold it but now i'm getting other erro.

* Adding </home/marcio/testar> to PYTHONPATH and MORSE_RESOURCE_PATH.

* Using default scene in environment <testar>.

* morse 1.2-10-gf0bcf

connect failed: No such file or directory
morse.actuators.keyboard.Keyboard: no interfaces available for this component! Trying to use default one for socket.
GPUShader: linking error:
error: all shaders must use same shading language version

GPUShader: linking error:
error: all shaders must use same shading language version

Gpu problem, do you now how to solve it?

Comment: I'm only vaguely familiar with MORSE but I'm pretty certain it is a python module that is intended to be used from within blender. It sounds like you are having trouble building MORSE not blender. You also say your building 2.69 but the path shows 2.63a. I suggest having a close read of MORSE installation and troubleshooting docs, also try their mailing lists. MORSE is a bit more specialised project and you may not get anyone here that knows it.